# Quitar espacios del inicio al hacer un insert

Tags: c#

Como puedo quitar el espacio en blanco al hacer el `insert`,he intentado con `TrimStart()` y `Trim` y cuando se registra, queda asi `" XXXX"` en vez de asi `"XXX"`

```
comando.Parameters.Add(":NOMBRE",NOMBRE.TrimStart());
```

Comment: que tipo de dato defines en la tabla? es mas que base de datos usas? imagino es Oracle, pero deberias mencionarlo

Comment: si usas `string nombre = NOMBRE.Trim();` si pasas el mouse por sobre la variable puede ver que aun tiene los espacios